# position li tag at the middle of ul tag vertically

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a `ul` tag with `height:300px` and some `li` tags inside it.

```
<ul>
   <li> some text</li>
   <li> some other text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to  position this list at the middle of the ul tag vertically.
I dont want to set `posittion:absolute` .
I test the css below, but it does not work!

```
ul{
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li{
  margin:auto;
}
```

please give me some css !

Comment: have you tried using percentage? like `top:50%; left:50%;` then do a `margin-left:-50px; margin-top:-50px;`

Comment: it is not the solution, because of several numbers of li tags inside the ul tag. I want all of them to be positioned vertically at the middle.

Comment: just make the `ul` appear in the middle of wherever it is. Or am I missing something? Can we get some more of the structure of your page?

Comment: your style for ul {vertical-align: middle}; does not do anthing because vertical-align ONLY works for inline or inline-block elements. Give li a line-height of 300px same as the height of ul and it will align vertically.

Comment: Also your style for li {margin: auto;}; is wrong. It should be li {margin: 0 auto;}.

Comment: And please use @ for your comments so that I will get messages in my inbox directly without re-visiting the question for see any updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

#### CSS

```
ul {
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: lime;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}​
```

#### DEMO

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUAzv/)

Comment: Really. New Age CSS3 and we can't get ver/hor alignment without the use of tables. Be it even CSS styles duplicating table layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, but it requires an additional element with the fixed height (300px in this instance). The `UL` element is then allowed to default to `height: auto;`, and is vertically-aligned to the middle by a hidden psuedo-element.

[jsfiddle: Element vertically aligned to the middle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/RD3Fy/)

The pseudo-element is positioned outside and to the left of the containing element, and set as `vertical-align: middle;`.

```
container:before {
  cotent: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This allows the container's child elements to vertically-align themselves to the pseudo-element, which has the parent element's height.